# "react-native-loading-spinner-overlay" is not working when modal is open in iOS

Tags: react-native

"react-native-loading-spinner-overlay" is not working when modal is open in iOS. If I set modal visible to false, it works.
(Android is working well in any case.)
That is my code.

> When modal is open, if I click upload button on modal,

```
  _onUpload = () => {
    this.setState({ isLoading: true }) //-----> Loading spinner is not working.
  }
```

> If I make like this

```
  _onUpload = () => {
    this.setState({ modalVisible:false })  //-----> After modal turns off
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.setState({ isLoading: true })   //----> Loading spinner works.
    }, 500);
  }
```

> render

```
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Spinner
          visible={this.state.isLoading}
          textContent={'Loading...'}
          textStyle={{ color: 'white' }}
        />
      </View>
    )
  }
```

I used modal from 'react-native-modal'

> import Modal from 'react-native-modal';

```
<Modal
  isVisible={modalVisible}
  backdropColor="#B4B3DB"
  backdropOpacity={0.8}
  animationIn="zoomInDown"
  animationOut="zoomOutUp"
  animationInTiming={1000}
  animationOutTiming={1000}
  backdropTransitionInTiming={1000}
  backdropTransitionOutTiming={1000}>
  <View style={styles.modalBody}>
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this._onUpload()} >
      <Text>Upload</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  </View>
</Modal>
```

Why it is not working on only iOS?

How to make it work on iOS when modal is open?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use one Modal on another Modal in ios,
you have to close the first Modal before opening a second Modal.

like,

```
setstate({isLoading:false,modalVisible:true})
```

or you can use ternary like,

```
{modalVisible?
<View style={styles.modalBody}>
<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this._onUpload()} >
  <Text>Upload</Text>
</TouchableOpacity>
</View: null}
```

Comment: "loading-spinner" is also modal?

Comment: that's why it's not working you have to isLoading:false then modalVisible:true will work.

Comment: I want to set isLoading true.

Answer (score 1):

Add a timeout to wait for the first Modal to close.

```
         setTimeout(() => {
           setstate({modalVisible:true})
         }, 2000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Creating your own spinner is the best option I come across for this issue.

```
{showSpinner && (
        <View style={{ ...StyleSheet.absoluteFill, zIndex: 1 }}>
          <ActivityIndicator color={Colors.gray900} size="large" style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: Colors.gray300, opacity: 0.3 }} />
        </View>
        )}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `onDismiss` or `onModalHide` for IOS and for Android use old solution with Platform condition.

```
<Modal
   isVisible={modalVisible}
   onRequestClose={() => {
      if (Platform.OS !== 'ios'){
         setLoading(true);
      }
   }}
   onDismiss={() => {
      setLoading(true);
   }}
>
</Modal>
```